# can I lazy load entries?

Tags: templating

is it possible to retrieve for example 50 entries. Show 10 entries on my template and with "more" loading 10 more entries and so on and show them on the same page?

Whats the best practice for this? Do I need a plugin for this?

Comment: There's complete example code in this Q/A on how you'd do that.

Comment: Or here: [Dynamically load craft entries based on twig variable](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1566/125)

Comment: A good question nonetheless.